# In Python, can I pass a global variable in a function after it has been changed during runtime?

Tags: python, global-variables

I suspect I have run into a limitation of Python, but I just want to make sure...

```
GLOBAL_VAR = "foo"

def printVar(myVar=GLOBAL_VAR):
    print myVar

def changeVar(newVar):
    global GLOBAL_VAR
    GLOBAL_VAR = newVar

printVar()

OUTPUT: foo

changeVar('bar')
print GLOBAL_VAR

OUTPUT: bar

printVar()

OUTPUT: foo
```

Why isn't the last output 'bar'?

Comment: Where have you defined foo and bar (you are trying to OUTPUT: them)?  Your code works fine otherwise.  What is the purpose of this program and what version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the assignment `myVar=GLOBAL_VAR` is evaluated when the function is defined - and at that time, `GLOBAL_VAR` is `"foo"`.

You could change your function like this:

```
def printVar(myVar=None):
    if(myVar is None):
        myVar = GLOBAL_VAR
    print myVar
```

That way it will always print the current value of `GLOBAL_VAR`

Comment: If OP wants to verify this they can use `inspect.getargspec(printVar)`

Comment: See [Mutable Default Arguments](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/gotchas/)

Comment: That's what I suspected.  Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 0):

The default binding is done when the `def` statement is executed -- in short, when you first parse that line, on the first pass through your program.  The value then is "foo", so that's the default value for `myVar`.  You can change `GLOBAL_VAR`, but that binding is still to the *value*, not a reference to the variable.

If you want to change the binding, you need to execute the `def` again -- in other words, you have to redefine the function.